# elastic search sort aggregation by selected field

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I sort the output from an aggregation by a field that is in the source data, but not part of the output of the aggregation?

In my source data I have a date field that I would like the output of the aggregation to be sorted by date.

Is that possible? I've looked at using "order" within the aggregation, but I don't think it can see that date field to use it for sorting?

I've also tried adding a sub aggregation which includes the date field, but again, I cannot get it to sort on this field.

I'm calculating a hash for each document in my ETL on the way in to elastic. My data set contains a lot of duplication, so I'm trying to use the aggregation on the hash field to filter out duplicates and that works fine. I need the output from the aggregation to retain a date sort order so that I can work with the output in angular.

The documents are like this:

```
{_id: 123,
_source: {
"hash": "01010101010101"
"user": "1"
"dateTime" : "2001/2/20 09:12:21"
"action": "Login"
}

{_id: 124,
_source: {
"hash": "01010101010101"
"user": "1"
"dateTime" : "2001/2/20 09:12:21"
"action": "Login"
}


{_id: 132,
_source: {
"hash": "0202020202020"
"user": "1"
"dateTime" : "2001/2/20 09:20:43"
"action": "Logout"
}

{_id: 200,
_source: {
"hash": "0303030303030303"
"user": "2"
"dateTime" : "2001/2/22 09:32:14"
"action": "Login"
}
```

So I want to use an aggregation on the hash value to remove duplicates from my set and then render the response in date order.

My query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "action": "Login"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "size": 0,
        "aggs": {
          "md5": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "hash",
              "size": 0
            }
          },
          "size": 0,
          "aggs": {
            "byDate": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "dateTime",
                "size": 0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Currently the output is ordered on the hash and I need it ordered on the date field within each hash bucket. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you share the index type schema you're using and the elasticsearch query as well?

Comment: I just updated the post with more detail. Thanks!

Comment: The query is invalid json, you're missing some stuff, like the colon after "bool", it should be `"boo" : { "must"`

Comment: Thanks, I have a working query, but I dont have copy paste available between dev and desktop, so I just typed it out quickly, the query does work to return buckets, I just need all results to get date sorted across all the buckets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the aggregation on "hash" is just for removing duplicates, it might work for you to simply aggregate on "dateTime" first, followed by the `terms` aggregation on "hash". For example:

```
GET my_index/test/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "bool": {
          "must" : [
            { "term": {"action":"Login"} }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "byDate" : {
      "terms": {
        "field" : "dateTime",
        "order": { "_term": "asc" }   <---- EDIT: must specify order here
      },
      "aggs": {
        "byHash": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "hash"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This way, your results would be sorted by "dateTime" first.

Comment: Thanks, I did look at that but as datetime is not unique and there are definitely valid instances of two different events with the same datetime, I couldn't find a way to loop through the response in angular to render the output. It seems like it will be easier to work with the output data if the unique field is the first field.

Comment: I've just tried this on a large data set and the aggregation buckets do not get returned in date order. What I would like to do is have the aggegations returned in date order not just within the buckets, but across all the buckets if you see what I mean. So bucket 1 would contain the earlier data and then the last bucket contains the latest data. Thanks!

Comment: @ADev, sorry about that, I forgot to add the `order` option to the `terms` aggregation. By default, `terms` orders the buckets by doc count. If you want to order by the terms themselves, you need to specify `_term` order. I have edited my answer to include this necessary piece. Hope this helps!

Comment: in ES6 the `_term` is deprecated as aggregation order key use `_key` instead: `"order": { "_key": "asc" }`